# Простая математическая формула как это можно сделать на c++

Tags: c++, математика

Не знаю как делать это, заранее спасибо
[image: задали в универе]

Comment: Циклом, меняя счетчик от 0 до n-1 и умножая на a+счетчик...

Answer (score 1):

Если время не важно-можно циклом. Если входные данные большие, то лучше по формуле сложения последовательности чисел находите все члены и перемножаете. Здесь решение циклом:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int a, n;
cin >> a >> n; // получаем числа 
int answer = a; // переменная - ответ
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    ans *= (a + i); 
// первая итерация = a * (a + 1), вторая итерация = (a * (a + 1)) * (a + 2), и так далее
}
cout << ans;
return 0;
}
```